# How To Adjust The Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

In my program, I have this problem

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqzAD.png)

The edit text stays on top of the toolbar but I want the edit text to stay below the toolbar like a normal layout.

I changed the activity theme to `AppTheme.NoActionBar` because if I have normal AppTheme i cannot use the custom toolbar

**activity_definicoes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/content_definicoes" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_maps"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_maps_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_definicoes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="Raio"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**app_bar_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_maps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.casimiro.pap.MapsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: content_maps referring to content_definicoes.xml?

Comment: Drawer layout is supposed to have only two direct layout children, you should try making your two layouts into one

Comment: @Exigente05 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

> Inside the DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

There is more than that in your layout.

Change to it,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/content_maps" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with width and height of match_parent and no layout_gravity>. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a fixed width.

problem 1

you should only add your main content as the first child of the drawerLayout. here you have two childs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"        
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <include layout="@layout/content_maps" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_maps"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_maps_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not add more than two child inside [android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

You can do this,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include android:id="@+id/top"
    layout="@layout/content_maps" />

<include
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

OR,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/content_maps" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```